# $_FILES['file']['name'] in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I get the filename of the file uploaded in codeigniter. We get the values of the input fields as $this->input->post('name'), but how can i get the name of the file uploaded from the form??

```
  public function create(){

        //getting all the POST data in $data array
        $data = array('title' => $this->input->post('title') ,
              'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
              'filename' => ?? HOW ??
        );
}
```

Comment: The CI [User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) as all the info. You need to use `$this->upload->data()` ..

Comment: Please post your form in view.

Answer (score 3):

1) make sure that you form is multipart. With helper its `form_open_multipart()`

2) use upload library for receiving the file

3) then with `$this->upload->data()` you get array with file info

[Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) is full how to and official documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function create(){

        //getting all the POST data in $data array.
        $data = array('title' => $this->input->post('title') ,
              'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
              'filename' => $_FILES["file"]["name"]
        );
}
```